# Swift: Extending Array "containsValue" Equatable

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, generics, swift

I'm trying to extend a Swift array to add a method containsValue which will return a bool if a given value exists.

```
extension Array
{

    func containsValue(value: T) -> Bool
    {
        for item in self
        {
            if item == value
            {
                return true
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But this gives the following error on the `if item == value` line.

`Cannot invoke == with an argument list of type (T, T)`

How can I compare the given values in a generic way so I can add this extensions to my array?

edit: I found a global function [contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037699/swift-arrays-and-contains-crashes-when-var-is-string-but-when-i-cast-it-to-st) which does the trick. But I am still curious, how could I achieve this with the generics?

Comment: You need to make it type safe

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: do you need it to work with all types or only array of strings ?

Comment: That is the idea. With all [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Equatable.html) types.

Comment: you might take a look at Martin R answer to my question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794282/how-do-i-make-my-operator-work-with-double-and-int

Comment: btw I took almost a week to understand his explanation kkkkk

Comment: I have done a function that shuffles an array with any type if you would like to take a look I can post it for you

Comment: Sure, that might use a comparable mechanism.

Comment: Actually the other question where I check the base type might be easier for you to start with

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26795903/2303865

Comment: You (currently) *cannot* define an extension method which is only defined for certain restricted types, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value.